# New tag, is there a post explaining it? Kaitou Tenshi Twin Angel

Tags: support, status-completed

I have heard of a post, question, or meta process to request new tags for new anime, but I looked around and did not find it.

Can someone make a tag for [Kaitou Tenshi Twin Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kait%C5%8D_Tenshi_Twin_Angel) ([MAL](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3805/Kaitou_Tenshi_Twin_Angel))?

Comment: you do have the privilege for [creating tags](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). i generally follow the guideline [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/522/1587) but if you're having trouble in choosing a name you can post on Meta here seeking community assistance in what to choose

Comment: Oh I just presumed I didn't have the privilege.  I imagined tag creation was a high level ability.  I'm barely used to having enough rep to comment lol

Answer (score 5):

I see that user Darjeeling already [added the tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/39789/3) on [your question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39789/music-by-the-villain-in-ep-1-of-kaitout-tenshi-twin-angel). Hooray!

For future reference, any user with 150+ reputation, like you, [can create tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). The problem we run into is that completely new users (starting at 1 rep) or users who only have [the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/) (starting at 101 rep) aren't quite there, and hence must resort to some sort of workaround. Any of the following are acceptable if you can't find a tag for a question you'd like to ask:

- Tag your question with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) (which you can also find by entering "anime" or "manga" into the tag field)
- Tag your question with any arbitrary tag, and [flag your own post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as "in need of moderator intervention" (provided that you have the requisite 15+ reputation)
- Or, honestly, just post your question in any manner you'd like. Our question volume is low enough that somebody with enough reputation is almost certain to notice and fix the tags on your post in short order.

Whichever you do, just be sure that the text of your question is explicit about which anime/manga/etc you're asking about.